# Accessing objects on one nib file from another nib file

Tags: cocoa, macos, interface-builder

I have two nib files - `Main.nib` and `Preference.nib`
In `Main.nib` file I have an instance of `NSView` class. Its window has a `NSPopUpButton` which on clicking shows a menu. In the menu I have show Preferences menu item.
Menu item on clicking shows a preferences panel containing a color well item.
On clicking color well a color panel is displayed to choose the color. 
The problem is how to apply  that color to main application window.

My preference panel window is in Preference.nib file.
So problem is accessing `NSView` from another Nib Window.

Is there a way so that I can make connection between preference panel and my main application window(`NSView`)

Answer (score 2):

You're thinking about this at the wrong level. `NSView` and `NSWindow` are view objects in the Model-View-Controller pattern and shouldn't be used for holding application data. The color you select in your preference panel is application data and should be stored in an appropriate model object.

You could, for example, use bindings to bind the color well to the `NSUserDefaultsController` object to store that data (assuming this is an application-wide setting). You didn't say exactly what the color is used for in your main window, but if the object that uses it is  bindings aware, you can bind that object to the same value on the `NSUserDefaultsController` and you're done.

Otherwise, you can respond to the color well's action message to store the color in an appropriate place and then send a notification using `NSNotificationCenter` to tell other objects that the color has changed. You'll need to sign up any object that needs to take action when the value changes for your notification message.

Here are some resources:

- Here's an [overview of the model-view-controller](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH6-SW1) pattern that explains how Cocoa programs are structured
- This is a [high level explanation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/cocoabindings/CocoaBindings.html) of how Cocoa bindings work
- Here's a [bunch of documents about using notifications](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Notifications/Introduction/introNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000043-SW1)